# CPU utilization - not getting load balanced

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

On **Ubuntu 12.04** `mysqld` is using 100% of the CPU and I am wondering why it is not being load-balanced among the 4 cores. Is there way to do it manually? Or should I optimize MySQL?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

- MySQL **will** use all cores you trow at it
- But only for **parallelizable** workloads

Basicall this means, that every single query will execute on a single core, but concurrently running queries will run on different cores. So a single, CPU-expensive query is quite likely to produce such a `top` output, but other queries arriving from clients will not create a CPU concurrency.